# Dynamic Nested Tabs with jQuery and HTML

Tags: jquery, html, tabs, nested

I need help with some code;

1. I can't figure out why the links wont work,
2. Why the content wont display properly,
3. Using <"li"> with a <"a"> with grid col-xx-x"

[Here is a picture of what i'm trying to achieve "minus the small bullets"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUHMg.png)

The Tab links are suppose to show the associated content in the area called content. However the links, or more likely the jQuery isn't working as it should, please help.

HTML

```
<div class="4_steps" style="margin-top: 10%; margin-bottom: 10%;">  
<div class="tabs panel">
    <div class="number" style="text-align:center;">How does the Delivery Process work?</div>
    <div class="row"
    <ul class="tab-links" style="bullet:none">
        <li class="active col-md-3 col-centered">
            <a href="#tab11">
            <img style="height: 50%;" src="/editable/images/user/image/Restaurant%20Services/RS_4STEP_1.png" width="150" height="250" alt="">
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="col-md-3 col-centered">
            <a href="#tab12">
            <img style="height: 50%;" src="/editable/images/user/image/Restaurant%20Services/RS_4STEP_2.png" width="150" height="250" alt="">
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="col-md-3 col-centered">
            <a href="#tab13">
            <img style="height: 50%;" src="/editable/images/user/image/Restaurant%20Services/RS_4STEP_3.png" width="150" height="250" alt="">
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="col-md-3 col-centered">          
            <a href="#tab14">
            <img style="height: 50%;" src="/editable/images/user/image/Restaurant%20Services/RS_4STEP_4.png" width="150" height="250" alt="">
            </a>
        </li>   
    </ul>
    </div
    <hr  size="3px" width="75%">
    <div class="content" style="margin-top: 25px;">
        <div id="tab11" class="tab" style="display: block;">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="textbox col-sm-6">
                        <h3>Customer places order 1 of 3 ways</h3>
                        <p class="message">We offer customers several ways to order food; they can order off our website, android and iOS apps or they can even call the order into our call center.<br>
                        <br>
                        The website supports our loyalty program, catering, group ordering and many other amazing features. The customer receives order notifications as the order progresses. The iOS and android apps are very helpful for placing an order on the go. Lastly we have a dedicated call center to handle all phone orders.<br>
                        <br>
                        Our dispatcher looks the order over for obvious errors and then sends the order to the restaurant and driver.</p>
                    </div>  
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <img width="100%" height="100%" alt="" src="/editable/images/user/image/Restaurant%20Services/ordering_picture.png">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="tab12" class="tab" style="display: none;">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="textbox col-sm-6">
                        <h3>We send orders to any device that has internet</h3>
                        <p class="message" style="">We offer several ways to send the orders to you, we offer fax, email and a new way via our website.<br>
                        <br>
                        The fax has been the default method for years. The driver will call to confirm fax received, this is done by your staff member telling the driver what the order number is. Having the fax near where phone orders are taken would be ideal.<br>
                        <br>
                        The email method works almost exactly the same as fax, only difference being how it is transmitted. When the orders arrive in your inbox, a script will send the order to your printer automatically. Requires a PC and printer to be turned on all day and a driver would need to call and confirm the order.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="textbox col-sm-6">
                        <p class="message" style="">We can also send the orders directly to any mobile device that can access the internet and use a browser. Simply go back to the landing page and create a new customer account, we will upgrade the account to a vendor and once logged in you will see orders as they come in. The device will beep until someone touches the device to look at the order, this also confirms the order so there's no need for the driver to call to confirm.<br>
                        <br>
                        As for what is the best method? We recommend a combination, one of either a fax or email and one vendor portal. This offers the best of both worlds; a printed copy for the customer and auto confirm feature of the web portal. The web portal can also show you a history of orders, view, print past orders and make minor menu edits.</p>
                        <img src="/editable/images/user/image/Restaurant%20Services/Restaruant_portal1.png" alt="" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </div>
        </div>  
        <div id="tab13" class="tab" style="display: none;">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="textbox col-sm-6">
                        <h3>Menu 2</h3>
                        <p class="message">We utilize local contractors and existing delivery companies to manage the delivery process itself. Each contract is done so on a progressive pay structure that not only holds the drive accountable, but also encourages growth and personal investment.<br>
                        <br>
                        Our customers expect hot and fresh food, which is why each driver is furnished with the best bags in the world. These bags have a antibacterial liner that ensures the container is germ free. They keep the food at the appropriate temperature for up to an hour, even though most orders are delivered in 15 minutes. They also manage the amount of moisture in the bag, ensuring food isn't dry or soggy.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="textbox col-sm-6">
                    <img width="100%" height="100%" alt="" src="/editable/images/user/image/Restaurant%20Services/LD_DeliveryBags_05.png" style="max-width: 800px;">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="tab14" class="tab" style="display: none;">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">   
                    <div class="textbox col-sm-6">
                        <h3>Menu 3</h3>
                        <p class="message">After a two week processing period and lesser our commission, all the sales including tax is deposited to your account every two weeks. We include a report of the sales with each payment, which allows management to quickly reconcile our account.<br>
                        <br>
                        Couple thoughts to consider; these are sales your business wouldn't otherwise be getting, we also manage the entire process including the advertising of the service to the public. Which has the added benefit of attracting more inside customers from our exposure. We also take the burden of credit card fees and charges associated with credit card transactions.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <img width="100%" height="100%" src="/editable/images/user/image/Restaurant%20Services/web_plain_calendar_restaurants.png" alt="">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('.tabs .tab-links a').on('click', function(e)  {
    var currentAttrValue = jQuery(this).attr('href');

    // Show/Hide Tabs
    jQuery('.tabs ' + currentAttrValue).show().siblings().hide();

    // Change/remove current tab to active
    jQuery(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

    e.preventDefault();
}); });
```

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that you did not close your div tags properly.

```
<div class="4_steps" style="margin-top: 10%; margin-bottom: 10%;">  
<div class="tabs panel">
    <div class="number" style="text-align:center;">How does the Delivery Process work?</div>
    <div class="row"        //this part
    <ul class="tab-links" style="bullet:none">
        <li class="active col-md-3 col-centered">
            <a href="#tab11">
            <img style="height: 50%;" src="/editable/images/user/image/Restaurant%20Services/RS_4STEP_1.png" width="150" height="250" alt="">
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="col-md-3 col-centered">
            <a href="#tab12">
            <img style="height: 50%;" src="/editable/images/user/image/Restaurant%20Services/RS_4STEP_2.png" width="150" height="250" alt="">
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="col-md-3 col-centered">
            <a href="#tab13">
            <img style="height: 50%;" src="/editable/images/user/image/Restaurant%20Services/RS_4STEP_3.png" width="150" height="250" alt="">
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="col-md-3 col-centered">          
            <a href="#tab14">
            <img style="height: 50%;" src="/editable/images/user/image/Restaurant%20Services/RS_4STEP_4.png" width="150" height="250" alt="">
            </a>
        </li>   
    </ul>
    </div    //this part also
```

Don't really understand what you mean by:

> Using <"li"> with a <"a"> with grid col-xx-x"

**Update:**
Replaced the "Jquery" with "$" and there is nothing wrong with the script. 
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.tab-links a').on('click', function(e)  {
        var currentAttrValue = $(this).attr('href');

```
    // Show/Hide Tabs
    $('.tabs ' + currentAttrValue).show().siblings().hide();

    // Change/remove current tab to active
    $(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

    e.preventDefault();
}); });
```

It is working; please look at the `display` of your code. You placed `display:none`.

```
<div id="tab12" class="tab" style="display:block;">
```

Comment: Hey thanks @cweitat. What I meant, when I said (<"li"> with a <"a"> with grid col-xx-x") Is there any restrictions when using a combination of lists and other tags with attributes like col-xx-x. My main issue is the links not working they don't display the content as intended, I was questioning whether this tab-links section was to blame.

Comment: Refer to http://jsfiddle.net/vym22aLe/
It's working. However I'm not sure how it should looks because there is no CSS files or image files inside.